Как сделать что бы swiper прокручивал только на один слайд
Когда устанавливаю loop={true} для бесконечной прокрутки, то часто при сильном свайпе, слайдер прокручивается не на один слайд, а сразу на два, особенно это видно когда в слайдере всего два слайда - https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/swiper-react-default-forked-s76gqc?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A30%2C13&workspaceId=e3e0f98e-e353-4914-9cc7-f8dd33f30511. (имеется ввиду когда свайпишь в браузере в режиме эмуляции мобильного устройства тач собыия) Выглядит это странно т.к. пользователь вроде бы и свайпнул, но по факту из-за прокрутки сразу на два слайда, вернулся на начальный слайд.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, что бы при свайпе, слайдер всегда прокручивался только на одни слайд?
